# Q: Requesting Permissions at Run Time, When and Where?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a little app for android phone, which need to read files on external storage (SD). As from 6.0, you must Request this Permissions at Run Time.

I did this as the given APIs, but I found I must CALL readfile() at 2 places, how to improve to avoid this??

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        else {

            LoadWords("testfile.txt");




        }




}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0&& grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    LoadWords("testfile.txt");

                } else {
                    maxlines = 0;
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lib : https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

This is a example activity with permission:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AppSettingsDialog;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String[] LOCATION_AND_CONTACTS =
            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};

    private static final int RC_CAMERA_PERM = 123;
    private static final int RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM = 124;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Button click listener that will request one permission.
        findViewById(R.id.button_camera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cameraTask();
            }
        });

        // Button click listener that will request two permissions.
        findViewById(R.id.button_location_and_contacts).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationAndContactsTask();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean hasCameraPermission() {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }

    private boolean hasLocationAndContactsPermissions() {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, LOCATION_AND_CONTACTS);
    }

    private boolean hasSmsPermission() {
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(RC_CAMERA_PERM)
    public void cameraTask() {
        if (hasCameraPermission()) {
            // Have permission, do the thing!
            Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: Camera things", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Ask for one permission
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.rationale_camera),
                    RC_CAMERA_PERM,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM)
    public void locationAndContactsTask() {
        if (hasLocationAndContactsPermissions()) {
            // Have permissions, do the thing!
            Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: Location and Contacts things", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Ask for both permissions
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.rationale_location_contacts),
                    RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM,
                    LOCATION_AND_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // EasyPermissions handles the request result.
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionsGranted:" + requestCode + ":" + perms.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionsDenied:" + requestCode + ":" + perms.size());

        // (Optional) Check whether the user denied any permissions and checked "NEVER ASK AGAIN."
        // This will display a dialog directing them to enable the permission in app settings.
        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            new AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == AppSettingsDialog.DEFAULT_SETTINGS_REQ_CODE) {
            String yes = getString(R.string.yes);
            String no = getString(R.string.no);

            // Do something after user returned from app settings screen, like showing a Toast.
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.returned_from_app_settings_to_activity,
                              hasCameraPermission() ? yes : no,
                              hasLocationAndContactsPermissions() ? yes : no,
                              hasSmsPermission() ? yes : no),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

It is easily to use.
I hope it can help your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class like this with override method like this

```
public abstract class AbsRuntimePermission extends AppCompatActivity {
private SparseIntArray mErrorString;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mErrorString = new SparseIntArray();
}

public abstract void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode);

public void requestAppPermissions(final String[]requestedPermissions, final int stringId, final int requestCode) {
    mErrorString.put(requestCode, stringId);

    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    boolean showRequestPermissions = false;
    for(String permission: requestedPermissions) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        showRequestPermissions = showRequestPermissions || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission);
    }

    if (permissionCheck!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(showRequestPermissions) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), stringId, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AbsRuntimePermission.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
                }
            }).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    for(int permisson : grantResults) {
        permissionCheck = permissionCheck + permisson;
    }

    if( (grantResults.length > 0) && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permissionCheck) {
        onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
    } else {
        //Display message when contain some Dangerous permisson not accept
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), mErrorString.get(requestCode),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }).show();
    }
}
```

}

and in the main

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hallfinder);

    requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,},
            R.string.msg, REQUEST_PERMISSION);

}
```

Hope it will help you